# Resample time series excluding nan data

Tags: pandas, resampling

I have a daily data time series in which there are many NaN values. I want to resample to monthly data taking account only months with less than 10 day NaN values.

I've tried using the resample function, by this way:

> ```
> df = 
> Date          Sr_1    Sr_2    Sr_3
> 01/12/1978    32.2    20.8    NaN
> 02/12/1978    32.2    20.6    NaN
> 03/12/1978    31.6    22      NaN
> 04/12/1978    28.2    19.4    NaN
> 05/12/1978    29.8    22.8    24.6
> 06/12/1978    32      22.2    25.8
> 07/12/1978    32.8    23.2    NaN
> 08/12/1978    29.8    NaN     26.8
> 09/12/1978    31.4    21.4    25.4
> 10/12/1978    28.8    24      NaN
> 11/12/1978    30.8    20      NaN
> 12/12/1978    32      24      25.6
> 13/12/1978    33      23.2    25.8
> 14/12/1978    32.4    22.4    24.6
> 15/12/1978    30      20.6    NaN
> 16/12/1978    32.6    21.2    NaN
> 17/12/1978    33      23.4    NaN
> 18/12/1978    30.4    20.4    26.4
> 19/12/1978    32      22.2    NaN
> 20/12/1978    32.2    NaN     NaN
> 21/12/1978    32.8    22.8    NaN
> 22/12/1978    32      22.2    NaN
> 23/12/1978    32.2    NaN     NaN
> 24/12/1978    31.4    NaN     NaN
> 25/12/1978    33      NaN     25.6
> 26/12/1978    33.4    20.6    NaN
> 27/12/1978    33.6    22.2    NaN
> 28/12/1978    33.6    23.4    NaN
> 29/12/1978    33.8    23.4    NaN
> 30/12/1978    33.2    NaN     25.2
> 31/12/1978    33.6    23.4    25.2
> ```

```
df.resample('1MS', how='mean')
```

The result is:

> ```
> 01/12/1978    31.9    22.1    25.5
> ```

But Sr_3 have more than 10 NaN values, so the result must be NaN.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hackyish way. First count the number of NaNs then use where to NaN those out.

```
In [11]: g = df1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1MS'))
```

*Note: count by using [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) and `sum`.*

```
In [12]: g.apply(lambda x: pd.isnull(x).sum()).unstack(1)  # Note: columns match res
Out[12]:
            Sr_1  Sr_2  Sr_3
Date
1978-01-01     0     0     1
1978-02-01     0     0     1
1978-03-01     0     0     1
1978-04-01     0     0     1
1978-05-01     0     0     0
1978-06-01     0     0     0
1978-07-01     0     0     1
1978-08-01     0     1     0
1978-09-01     0     0     0
1978-10-01     0     0     1
1978-11-01     0     0     1
1978-12-01     0     5    13

In [13]: under_ten_nan = g.apply(lambda x: pd.isnull(x).sum()).unstack(1) <= 10
```

use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to NaN those entries over 10:

```
In [14]: res.where(under_ten_nan)
Out[14]:
             Sr_1   Sr_2  Sr_3
Date
1978-01-01  32.20  20.80   NaN
1978-02-01  32.20  20.60   NaN
1978-03-01  31.60  22.00   NaN
1978-04-01  28.20  19.40   NaN
1978-05-01  29.80  22.80  24.6
1978-06-01  32.00  22.20  25.8
1978-07-01  32.80  23.20   NaN
1978-08-01  29.80    NaN  26.8
1978-09-01  31.40  21.40  25.4
1978-10-01  28.80  24.00   NaN
1978-11-01  30.80  20.00   NaN
1978-12-01  32.51  22.36   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, intuitively I went by this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-filter the groups (using a similar algo as @Andy Hayden). Not sure if this is any less hacky!

This is new in 0.14.0 (you can you `pd.TimeGrouper('1MS')` in prior versions

```
In [20]: g = pd.Grouper(freq='1MS')
```

Filter and only keep groups where the column satisfy the criteria of having < 10 nans
Then do the resample (this is what `groupby(g).mean()` does)

```
In [28]: pd.concat([ 
                    df.groupby(g)[c].filter(lambda x: x.isnull().sum()<10).groupby(g).mean() 
                    for c in df.columns ],axis=1)

Out[28]: 
             Sr_1   Sr_2  Sr_3
Date                          
1978-01-01  32.20  20.80   NaN
1978-02-01  32.20  20.60   NaN
1978-03-01  31.60  22.00   NaN
1978-04-01  28.20  19.40   NaN
1978-05-01  29.80  22.80  24.6
1978-06-01  32.00  22.20  25.8
1978-07-01  32.80  23.20   NaN
1978-08-01  29.80    NaN  26.8
1978-09-01  31.40  21.40  25.4
1978-10-01  28.80  24.00   NaN
1978-11-01  30.80  20.00   NaN
1978-12-01  32.51  22.36   NaN
```

This has to be done columm by column and then concatted because filter works on the entire group.