# Find days where value passes threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries with values that are either above or below a threshold value (126.82). I need to group the values by day and calculate the mean mean, which i managed to do with

```
df.resample("1d").mean()
```

The part I am struggling with is, that I want NaN values for days, where there are values both above and below the threshold value. So the mean should only get calculated for days where all values are either above or below the threshold. In the table below the first and second day would be OK, the last should be NaN.

Example Data (in reality quarter-hourly values)

```
time                | value
2014-06-04 00:00:00 | 127.00
2014-06-04 06:00:00 | 128.00
2014-06-04 12:00:00 | 127.00
2014-06-04 18:00:00 | 128.00
2014-06-05 00:00:00 | 125.00
2014-06-05 06:00:00 | 124.00
2014-06-05 12:00:00 | 124.00
2014-06-05 18:00:00 | 125.00
2014-06-06 00:00:00 | 127.00
2014-06-06 06:00:00 | 126.00
2014-06-06 12:00:00 | 125.00
2014-06-06 18:00:00 | 128.00
```

Expected Result:

```
time        | mean value
2014-06-04  | 127.50  <-- all Values above threshold: get mean
2014-06-05  | 124.50  <-- all Values below threshold: get mean
2014-06-06  | NaN     <-- Values above and below threshold: get NaN
```

I tried modifying [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635234/resample-time-series-excluding-nan-data) but didn't have any luck so far.

Comment: Can anyone describe what he/she wants exactly from us? What is the sample result?

Comment: Please add a data sample (in code) for us to use, and how *exactly* an expected output should look like.

Comment: I tried to clarify the explanation and data, also added expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that might not be perfect, but provides the expected result (more or less)

Step 1:
Add two helper columns that contain the values of the timeseries shifted by +1 and -1

```
df["value +1"] =  df["value"].shift(1)
df["value -1"] =  df["value"].shift(-1)
```

Step 2:
Compare original value and shifted values with threshold.

```
t = 126.82
df["changed"] = (
                ((df["value"] >= t) & (df["value +1"] < t)) |
                ((df["value"] < t) & (df["value +1"] >= t)) |
                ((df["value"] >= t) & (df["value -1"] < t)) |
                ((df["value"] < t) & (df["value -1"] >= t)) |
                )
```

Step 3: Adept the solution from the [linked question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635234/resample-time-series-excluding-nan-data)

```
grouper = df["changed"].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1d'))
no_change = grouper.apply(lambda x: (x == True).sum()) == 0
df_daily_no_change = df.where(no_change).resample("1d").mean()
```

It might be cumbersome, but I get the data i need.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Before version 1.3.0, Pandas had a `where` function that could do exactly this. Since it's deprecated,</s> I would utilize `numpy.where` in this case. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Get the values array as a numpy array using `numpy.array(df[column_name])` and then use

```
numpy.where(array < threshold, array, numpy.NAN)
```

This should get the array you want, and you can then reset the dataframe column.

Separate example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.where(x > 3, x, np.NAN)
array([nan, nan, nan,  4.,  5., nan, nan, nan,  4.])
```

Comment: I don't know why you think that `where`  is deprecated, but this is not true.

Comment: That is my fault, I looked at the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html and didn't realize it was talking about the "try_cast" argument. I was very curious why they would remove that functionality.

Regardless, I'm still a fan of using numpy over pandas, especially in this case.

Comment: what is deprecated is the default value (see. [#38836](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/38836))

Comment: Yes, I simply misread it. I thought it was talking about the entirety of the `where` function. Apologies.

Comment: No worries, I just wondered what happened for a sec when I read you ;)

Comment: I realize now this doesn't completely answer the question. But OP really needs to give a better description of the problem.